# Best way to have script start up for all users in Mountain Lion?

Tags: mac, startup, plist

We are trying to have a simple drive mapping script start up for ALL users on a Mac Mini. What's the simplest way of going by doing this? I've tried creating a .plist in Lingon and adding it to the Library LauncherDaemons and LauncherAgents folders, but it's not starting up. Any ideas? Is there a way to do this in the Terminal? The script by itself works fine and works if we add it to the Startup Items in System Preferences, but we want this to be automatic and for all users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Save a property list like this as /Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>test</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>say</string>
            <string>aa</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

It should be loaded automatically on the next login.

See `man launchd`, `man launchctl`, and `man launchd.plist` for more information.

Comment: That worked perfectly! So how would I call up a .app script with this? Would I just put the path in a new string? Thanks. 

EDIT: Actually, it looks like it only worked for the user that added it (I made sure to put it in the system library too). Very weird.